# Error that history .push is not a function after clicking on signout in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting error that history .push is not a function after clicking on signout in ReactJS.

> ````
> TypeError: history.push is not a function (anonymous function) C:/Users/Rina/Desktop/NodeApp/Ecommerce/ecommerce-front/src/core/Menu.js:39 36 | <span className="nav-link" 37 | style={{cursor: 'pointer', color: '#ffffff'}} 38 | onClick={() => signout(() => { > 39 | history.push('/'); | ^ 40 | }) 41 | } 42 | >```
> ````

Comment: TypeError: history.push is not a function
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Rina/Desktop/NodeApp/Ecommerce/ecommerce-front/src/core/Menu.js:39
  36 | <span className="nav-link" 
  37 |       style={{cursor: 'pointer', color: '#ffffff'}} 
  38 |       onClick={() => signout(() => {
> 39 |           history.push('/');
     | ^  40 |       })
  41 |     }
  42 | >

Comment: great you added more details about your issue but just to let you know you can edit your original question and add it there. Formatting code in comments is really limited and you can achieve more by posting it in the answer directly!

Answer (score 0):

In History API there is no something like `history.push()`. Probably you wanted to use `history.pushState` you can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API?page=1

Comment: export const signout = (next) => {
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
        next();
        return fetch(`${API}/signout`, {
            method: "GET",
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('signout', response)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}

Comment: import React from 'react';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {signout} from '../auth/Index';

Comment: <li className="nav-item">
                        <span className="nav-link" 
                              style={{cursor: 'pointer', color: '#ffffff'}} 
                              onClick={() => signout(() => {
                                  history.pushState('/');
                              })
                            }
                        >
                            signout
                        </

Comment: If I write history.pushState instead of history.push. It still give error

Comment: TypeError: history.pushState is not a function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react hooks you can use like this

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

function SignOut() {
  const history = useHistory();
  
 .....

 history.push('/');


}
```